# Show that $e^{z+2j\pi n}=e^z, \forall z\in\mathbb{C},\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I've been trying to solve the following exercise for a while, but I haven't had a successful attempt

Show that $$e^{z+2j\pi n}=e^z, \forall z\in\mathbb{C},\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$$

Any help is appreciated

Comment: The proof depends on what you know on and how you define $e^z, e,\pi$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just let $z = x + jy$, whence we get that
\begin{align*}
\exp(z + 2j\pi n) & = \exp(x + yj + 2j\pi n)\\\\
& = \exp(x)\exp((y + 2\pi n)j)\\\\
& = \exp(x)(\cos(y + 2\pi n) + j\sin(y + 2\pi n))\\\\
& = \exp(x)(\cos(y) + j\sin(y))\\\\
& = \exp(x)\exp(yj)\\\\
& = \exp(x + yj)\\\\
& = \exp(z)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

$$e^{z+2j\pi n}=e^z \cdot e^{2j\pi n}=e^z \cdot 1 = e^z.$$